# Plotting $θ(x+2)+θ(x+1)+θ(x)x$

Tags: graphing-functions, step-function

The unit step function is given in a combinatory form $θ(x+2)+θ(x+1)+θ(x)x$

, so what we have here is:

for $x< 0$:

$θ(x+2)=1 \ \ \  when \ \ -2<x$

$θ(x+1)=1 \ \ \  when \ \ -1< x$

$θ(x)x=0 $

Then for $x> 0$:

$θ(x+2)=1 \ \ \  when \ \ -2<x$

$θ(x+1)=1 \ \ \  when \ \ -1< x$

$θ(x)x=x $

So I thought we would get a straight horizontal line for $x<0$ at y=1, and then $y=x+1$ from $x>0$.

But wolfram plots this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%CE%B8%28x%2B2%29%2B%CE%B8%28x%2B1%29%2B%CE%B8%28x%29x

Why, and is my assumption not correct?

Comment: Thanks! Corrected

Comment: I can't make any sense out of the equations you have written.

Comment: Thanks  @Moo, but  with $θ(x+2)=1 \ \ \  when \ \ -2<x$

$θ(x+1)=1 \ \ \  when \ \ -1< x$  why doesn't the horizontal line start from -2 and goes through -1, and remains at y=1? In wolfram, it makes a ladder in this region. What I mean is that it heaviside function is either 0 or 1 on the y-axis, Here it makes several steps over these two values.

Comment: Can you work it out from what I posted now?

Comment: Thanks Moo...!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we plot the [*Heaviside Unit Step*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), $\theta(x)$, we get

[image]

If we now plot $\theta(x+2)$, this is just shifting the previous by two to the left, we get

[image]

If we plot, $θ(x+2)+θ(x+1)$, notice how we get a unit step at $-2$, but also get one at $-1$

[image]

If we plot, $θ(x+2)+θ(x+1)+θ(x)x$, notice how we have the unit step at $-2$, then $-1$ and then $0$. Since it is $1$ at $x \ge 0$, notice how it is just the line $x$ to the right.

[image]

Comment: So you added a unit to the existing unit horizontal line of $\theta(t+2)$ from the second  unit step function $\theta(t+1)$ and got 2 on the y-axis in that last interval before 0. Seems very important to me, when one says "unit step function is always 1 after 0", then it means it is "one unit more" than the previous interval, no matter what that previous interval was.